# Mesh simplification for regular surfaces except details

Tags: mesh, meshlab, simplification

I need to prepare 3D mesh of car seat to further dynamic analysis. Because the mesh has high resolution it is necessity to make a simplification using one of the available options in MeshLab. What module I have to use to get the mesh with lower resolution in places where the faces are simple (regular, simple surfaces) but higher resolution where details must be preserved (curvatures, folds, bends). The screen of the object I attach to this message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYPyV.jpg)

Thank you for any advice in advance.

Jakub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filters > Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction > Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation`

Then either enter the desired number of facets, or a percentage for how much the mesh should be reduced.

Check the following settings:

`Preserve Boundary of the mesh` --> Does not modify any existing boundary edges

`Preserve Normal` --> Maintains the normals of the mesh and prevents face-flipping

`Preserve Topology` --> Maintains the genus of the mesh (i.e., doesn't create or collapse holes)

`Optimal position of simplified vertices` --> Collapses edges onto the point which minimizes the quadric error

`Planar Simplification` --> Improves simplification in planar regions

`Post-simplification cleaning` --> Not sure if this is actually necessary, but it's always checked by default.

---

The quadric decimation algorithm reduces the number of facets by assigning a 'cost' to each edge based on the signed distance to the quadric plane. The algorithm sorts edges by cost and collapses edges which would produce the smallest error in the final mesh, which is exactly what you want.

An explanation of this algorithm can be found in a brief paper by Michael Garland titled [Surface Simplification Using Quadric Error Metrics](https://mgarland.org/files/papers/quadrics.pdf) or in his Ph.D. Dissertation, titled [Quadric-Based Polygonal Surface Simplification](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1999/CMU-CS-99-105.pdf)